# Cannot view deleted questions in app, even with enough rep

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, android-app

I have enough rep to view deleted questions (on SO), but when I try to do so from the Android app, I receive a warning that the question is deleted and the question itself is not shown.

Example of such deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17060619/2040040.

Comment: Not really a bug, just a missing feature.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Feel free to close as duplicate. @josh

Comment: Wow, I didn't think anyone ever actually used the app. It hasn't been consistently maintained in a long time. Why would you choose to use the app instead of the mobile version of the site?

Comment: @cody, the mobile version of the site is terrible for notifications, edits, ease of navigation. I kinda like the app, typing this right in it. But there's definitely some room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The app relies on the API, and the API does not (currently) offer any data for deleted posts.

Comment: That would explain it, thanks